# Can Google Cloud Build Trigger Substitution Variables exposed publicly?

Tags: firebase, next.js, google-cloud-build

In order to build my NextJS app, my Firebase Private Key is required at build time. Google Cloud Build has a feature called [Substituting variable values](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values).

I would like to know if there is a risk of someone being able to access this key publicly?

That is to assume I didn't write code that accidentally exposes the key.

Comment: It depends on what your definition of "safe" is.  Security is a very complex issue, and without understanding all your requirements and how information flows through your system, we can't really say how "safe" any of it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Secrets Manager](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets) to store your private key.  You're still passing it as an environment variable, but it's being done securely rather than you explicitly passing it as an env var directly.